# Linux last 5 logins for every user

Tags: linux, bash, awk, raspberry-pi

So i was trying to get X last logins for ALL users using a bash script but does anyone know how exactly to extract only a date so i can create a set in some sort of a table?
using last i get output like this:

```
yogi     pts/0        192.168.0.103    Fri Nov 18 07:04 - 07:05  (00:00)
yogi     pts/1        10.8.3.6         Thu Nov 17 14:36 - 16:53  (02:17)
yogi     pts/0        10.8.3.6         Thu Nov 17 14:32 - 16:45  (02:12)
```

and so with awk '{print $1, $4, $5, $6,}' i can only go that far
but is there away to get something like this:

```
name surname login date1 date2 date3 date4 etc.
```

Scratching my head around this for a while now ;/

Comment: Assuming that you are using the `last` command to extract this data, where do you suppose the `name` and `surname` fields are going to come from?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Fifth field in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: aye, that is where i was looking for, as far as i remember there is one field on which I'd have to run some awk magic again but that's the place to look  :)

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu awk:

```
$ cat program.awk
NR==FNR {
    split($5,a,",")
    b[$1]=a[1]
    next
} 
($1 in b) && ++c[$1]<=5 {
    d[$1]=d[$1] $4 " " $5 " " $6 (c[$1]==5?"":OFS)
} 
END {
    for (i in d) 
        print b[i], i, d[i]
}
```

Run it:

```
awk -f program.awk OFS=", " FS=":" /etc/passwd FS=" +" <(last)
James Brown, james, Sat Nov 19, Wed Nov 16, Tue Nov 15, Mon Nov 14, Sun Nov 13
```

Bad example since I'm on my laptop. The order of output is Gnu awk default ie. random. If change the for traverse order with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` if desired.

Comment: I was thinking about something that would prevent console from spitting to many lines. With 5 last logins for each user I'm trying to have each user only apear in a single line.
So we could have something like this:  
  
`name1 surname1 login1 date1 date2 date3 date4 date5`   
`name2 surname2 login2 date1 date2 date3 date4 date5`

Comment: @YoGi Apparently I lost my thought while coding the previous solution. Is this more like it?